# When are strings evaluated in Velocity?

Tags: performance, velocity

At which time are strings evaluated in Velocity? Directly at initialization or when referencing the string?

Example code to better illustrate the question:

```
#set($mystring = "A ${myobj.mymethod()} B")

#foreach($element in $somelist)
   $element $mystring
#end
```

So the string contains some velocity code. Then consider the following code:

```
#foreach($element in $somelist)
   $element A $myobj.mymethod() B
#end
```

Which is faster performance-wise, or are they equal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is faster, as the second method will call `$myobj.mymethod()` at each iteration.

But as long as this call isn't expansive, you may as well privilege code readability by reducing intermediate variables.

Comment: So the variable (here: `$mystring`) is indeed evaluated at initialization and not when referencing it. In my case it's more critical performance wise, so I do want to use an itermediate variable.